# Export model with multiple textures to Unreal Engine 4

Tags: texturing, materials, export, import, unreal-engine

I encountered difficulties importing a model with two textured materials from sketchup.

SketchUp image with a brick and timber texture from JPEG maps.
[image: sketchup image]

Blender recognizes my two materials as different 'UV maps' on the dropdown menu. Online tutorials recommend deleting the second UV map (ID19) and replacing it with a LightMap.

[image: Blender Picture]

However, after exporting my .fbx file and opening it in UE4, my second material disappears (brick texture disappears (color is there though!) but timber texture remains)

[image: UE4 Picture]

Could someone shed some light on how I can get the brick layer to come up? I am able to export with one single material on but not with two different materials on a model. I assume it is not to do with scale as the timber is scaled to the exact as the SU image.

Comment: @ARadish he is exporting from blender to unreal.

Comment: Unreal rather. but I still don't see how trying to get a brick texture to come up in Unreal is viable as a blender question.

Answer (score 1):

You replaced the brick texture with a lightmap. Try to skip that step and see what happens. Alternatively, you could texture the same thing in blender using material slots.